# useEffect re rendering context api consumer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-context

I am trying to understand and practice React hooks. I have the following code with me.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import DisplayUser from "./comp/DisplayUser";

const initialState = {
  firstStep: 0,
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { firstStep: state.firstStep + action.payload };
    case "decrement":
      return { firstStep: state.firstStep - action.payload };
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [tick, setTick] = useState(0);
  const [step, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };
  const decreaseCount = () => {
    console.log("De");
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTick((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, [tick]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section className="AppUseState">
        <h2>useState</h2>
        <article>
          <h4>Count : {count}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => increaseCount()}>Tick Plus</button>
          <button onClick={() => decreaseCount()}>Tick Minus</button>
        </article>
      </section>

      <section className="AppUseEffect">
        <h2>useEffect</h2>
        <article>
          <h4>Tick : {tick}</h4>
        </article>
      </section>

      <section className="AppUseReducer">
        <h2>useReducer</h2>
        <article>
          <h4>Step : {step.firstStep}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment", payload: 5 })}>
            Tick Plus
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement", payload: 3 })}>
            Tick Minus
          </button>
        </article>
      </section>

      <section className="AppUseContext">
        <h2>useContext</h2>
        <article>
          <UserContext.Provider value={{ userName: "Mohit" }}>
            <DisplayUser />
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Whenever a the setTick method in the setTimeout runs, its basically re rendering the DisplayUser component. (I have a console log in the DisplayUser component). My DisplayUser component looks like this

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../App";

function DisplayUser() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(user);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Hello from {user.userName}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default DisplayUser;
```

Can someone explain this behaviour to me as to why useEffect is basically re rendering my context api consumer component?

Comment: React component re-renders (along with all it children) in two cases - 1 when the state changes or when the props change... You're changing the state... You can look into `React.memo` and `React.useCallback` for optimizing renders...

Comment: `export default React.memo(DisplayUser);` instead of `export default DisplayUser;`.  Good Luck...